# how to connect react project to wordpress? to edit pages and collect data forms from website on wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

got my react website ready to deploy, decided to choose wordpress as backend supporter and can't find any proper tutorials or documentations how to connect frameworks between each other.
is there any tutors or maybe solution how to connect this thing with each other?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a Headless CMS instead. I use SRAPI, it's a good one and you can easily find a lot of tutorials about it